# winrt event drop dragenter etc.or zindex of image in grid

Tags: image, events, drag-and-drop, grid, windows-runtime

I have a winrt app with a grid. The grid contains images. What I want do is to drag one image over an other image inside the grid and change the position. The movement of the images i have made with Drag_ManipulationDelta and works well. With allowdrop=true and the drop event I thougt I can get the target image, but the drop event never fired. What is wrong or should I check?

So I tried different events, z.B. Pointer_moved etc. but if the events fires depends to the "position" of the image, If the moving Image is on top the underlaying image is not firing the events. So my next Idea is changing the zindex but image.zindex ist not existing. How can I chnage the zindex by code?

Any Ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the zindex I have solved: A simple

for each c in myGrid.children
c.setvalue(zindex, 0)
next

bring the images on the same level and

myimage.setvalue(zindex, -1)

brings the moving image behind all other images and now the pointer_entered event of the other images fires and I can detect the last fired event. It works but it is not really a good solution.

So it would be great, if anybody has a hint why the drop event is not working.